# How to break from inner *ngFor?

Tags: angular, typescript, group-by, ionic2, angular2-services

I've two array of Objects which I'm getting from a REST API. The first array contains jobId's and second one contains employee details. I need to display in such a way that for every job id all the employees with that job id need to be displayed in slides.

I know that `*ngFor` doesn't have a "break". I want to know what should I use? I don't know how exactly should I use a pipe here. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my typescript code:

```
import { Component,OnInit,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams,Slides  } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HttpService } from '../../providers/http-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-details',
  templateUrl: 'details.html',
  providers: [HttpService]
})
export class Details implements OnInit {
@ViewChild(Slides) slides: Slides;

empdetails:Array<any>=[];
jobs:Array<any>=[];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public httpService: HttpService) {}
 ngOnInit()
 {
   this.slides.lockSwipes(true);
   this.getempDetails();
   this.getJobDetailsfunc();
 }

getempDetails()
 {

     this.httpService.post('/getempdetails').subscribe(resp=>{
     this.empdetails = resp.data;
      });
 }

 getJobDetailsfunc()
 {
     this.httpService.post('/getJobDetails').subscribe(resp=>{
     this.jobs = resp.data;
      });
 }

 public showPrevious(): void {
    this.slides.lockSwipes(false);
     this.slides.slidePrev(500);
     this.slides.lockSwipes(true);
  }

  public showNext(): void {
    this.slides.lockSwipes(false);
    this.slides.slideNext(500);
    this.slides.lockSwipes(true);
  }
}
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<ion-slides>
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let jobObj of jobs">
        <ion-slide *ngFor="let empObj of empdetails; let i=index">
            <span *ngIf="jobObj.jobId==empObj.jobId">   checking for employees with same jobId and displaying their details
                  <h5>{{i+1}}</h5>                      Not able to break if jobId is different
            <span [innerHTML]="empObj.empName"></span>
            </span>
            <ion-row margin-top>
                <ion-col>
                    <button (click)="showPrevious()" ion-button text-only [disabled]="i === 0">Previous</button>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col>
                    <button *ngIf="i < empdetails.length - 1" (click)="showNext()" ion-button text-only>Next</button>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
        </ion-slide>    
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Some please tell me how to display it as per my requirement. I tried using

```
_.groupBy(this.empdetails,function(obj){
return obj.jobId});
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe by grouping it manually ?

```
this.myGroupedArray = this.jobs.reduce((prev, next) => {
    let pushObj = {
        id: next.id,
        employees: []
    };
    prev.push(pushObj);
}, []);

for (let employee of this.empdetails) {
    this.myGroupedArray.find(item => item.id === employee.jobId).employees.push(employee);
}
```

It probably isn't the best way to do it (and the complexity may be a bit too high), but I think it could solve your problem.

You now have a new array containing (for each job) your job ID, and every employee that has this ID in an array of employees.

Did this help you ?